# Every page now showing products page after install of WP E-Commerce

Tags: e-commerce, wordpress, product

I recently installed WP E-Commerce thinking it would be a snap to get a simple store running but after installation, no matter what page I go to, Wordpress loads the products page. I didn't change anything about my code and WP EC comes set to only appear on its "Products Page" so this doesn't make any sense to me.

Why is nothing ever as simple as it claims... why is there always some minor mystery snag that complete halts progress?? Frustrated.

Input or experience with this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind. I reverted to an older version until the current one is properly sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I found changing the permalink structure (and then changing it back if desired) fixed this very odd problem. It's mentioned on this thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-e-commerce-pagination-for-products-not-working